# react-native-firebase phone auth doesn't work on android

Tags: react-native-firebase

**Environment**: 
react-native 0.57.7,

react-native-firebase 5.1.1

**Problem**: Phone auth doesn't work on android. I tried both **signInWithPhoneNumber** and 
**verifyPhoneNumber** flows. The result is the same. When I call one of functions with real phone number error occurs but error object is empty (no info). For the test phone number I added manually in firebase console works fine. 
At the same time the same app work perfectly on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation showed that I need to add SHA-1 in project settings in the firebase console. After this auth starts to work.